# How to stop Preparing to rebalance group with old generation in Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I used Kafka for my web application and I found the below messages in kafka.log :

```
[2021-07-06 08:49:03,658] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group qpcengine-group in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 105 (__consumer_offsets-28) (reason: removing member consumer-1-7eafeb56-e6fe-4161-9c88-e69c06a0ab37 on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-07-06 08:49:03,658] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group qpcengine-group with generation 106 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-28) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

But, kafka like as looping forever for one consumer.
How can I stop it?

Here the picture of the kafka log :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVlcR.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one partition,you dont'need to use consumer_group
just try to use Assign(not subscribe）

Comment: thank's for your answer, I think my problem is solved by adding the MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG property with a value of 10800000, because the time it takes to process a consumer topic can reach 3 hours.

Comment: @learner the time it takes for you to process a single record takes up to 3 hours? or is it for the whole records in the topic?